# Identify Redshift COPY failing records in Ruby

Tags: ruby, copy, amazon-redshift, pg

When performing a `COPY` command, a few informations are printed, like :

```
INFO:  Load into table '<table>' completed, 22666 record(s) loaded successfully.
INFO:  Load into table '<table>' completed, 1 record(s) could not be loaded.  Check 'stl_load_errors' system table for details.
```

And I need to identify failing records.

Thus I need 2 things :

- Determine when there are failing rows: now, it's only printed on screen and I don't know how to get the message in code.
- Determine the failing rows.

One way to do that would be to access to the `query` identifier that is visible in the table `stl_load_errors`, but I have no clue how to access it by code.

(I currently use the `pg` gem to connect to redshift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stl_load_errors` is a table in Redshift that (as you may have guessed already) includes all the errors that happen when loading into Redshift. So you can query it by doing something like:

```
SELECT * FROM stl_load_errors
```

Now, to answer your questions use the following snippet:

```
database = PG.connect(redshift)
begin
  query = "COPY %s (%s) FROM 's3://%s/%s' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=%s;aws_secret_access_key=%s' CSV GZIP" %
[ table, columns, s3_bucket, s3_key, access_key_id, secret_access_key ]

  database.exec(query)
  puts 'File succesfully imported'
rescue PG::InternalError
  res = database.exec("SELECT line_number, colname, err_reason FROM pg_catalog.stl_load_errors WHERE filename = 's3://#{s3_bucket}/#{s3_key}'")
  res.each do |row|
    puts "Importing failed:\n> Line %s\n> Column: %s\n> Reason: %s" % row.values_at('line_number', 'colname', 'err_reason')
 end
end
```

That should output all the information you need, recall variables like `redshift`, `table`, `columns`, `s3_bucket`, `s3_key`, `access_key_id`, and `secret_access_key` depend on your configuration.

**UPDATE:**

To answer your comment below, more specifically, you could use a query like this:

```
"SELECT lines_scanned FROM pg_catalog.stl_load_commits WHERE filename = 's3://#{s3_bucket}/#{s3_key}' AND errors = -1"
```

Comment: Looks good, one more thing, do you have any idea to get the number of successfully loaded records ? (in this case, 22666, which is printed 'I don't know how').

Comment: The number of successfully loaded records is the same number of lines in the CSV you're importing; to my understanding if the COPY command fails nothing gets imported, so you need to fix the "broken" row and retry.

Comment: By using MAXERROR parameter in a COPY command, you can tell redshift to ignore failures without throwing an error. see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-load.html#copy-maxerror